# How can I see the final MySQL column value in a trigger even if it wasn't part of the update data?

Tags: mysql, triggers

How can I get the final value of a column in an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger even if I didn't update that specific column? Will `NEW.columnname` always have final value for that column?

If not, how can I get the final value?

On the [MySQL Trigger Manual Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html)
it says the following, which, to me is inconclusive:

> In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to the columns of the row after it is updated.

Does `NEW` refer to ALL the data of the row or just the submitted data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does NEW refer to ALL the data of the row or just the submitted data?*

Yes it (documentation) refers to all columns of a row that is being updated. Therefore you can safely use `NEW` keyword to address any columns, not only those that you actually updated.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2f9e/1)** demo. *Although only `col2` was updated all other columns were accessible.*